# What is a project supposed to be within a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: git, visual-studio, project

It is unclear how they are intended to be used.  But I am sure there is a notion that is assumed.

I assume something like a client-server system would reside in one solution.

Are projects always executables, or is a project built for an assembly?

I am assuming that multiple executables that have some shared code should go to one place for the code.  Where would that be?  A separate project?

When initializing, projects seem to be more independent entities than they should probably should be.  So I think a lot of people end up with relatively random programs lumped into one solution.

When branching with git, is it typical to have multiple independent branching schemes within a single solution (focused on particular projects)?

What I am asking for are some general guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx):

> Solutions contain items that you need in order to create your
> application. A solution includes one or more projects, plus files and
> metadata that help define the solution as a whole.
>
> [...]
>
> Projects are used in a solution to logically manage, build, and debug
> the items that make up your application. The output of a project is
> usually an executable program (.exe), a dynamic-link library (.dll)
> file or a module, among others.

---

For example, I was working with a certain nicely structured framework for computer graphics development. It is implemented as a single solution containing a dozen projects, such as `Core`,`OpenGL` and `Direct3D`. Each project gets compiled to its own `.dll` and thus an application that only uses some of the framework code does not need to be shipped with the full framework, as would be the case if the whole thing resided in a single project.

Not all of the projects resulted in `.dll` files, for example one of them was just a custom "New Project" wizard for Visual Studio (the wizard, once installed, can be used to easily create a customizable "blank" template application that is pre-configured to be able to use the framework and includes some skeleton code).

Using a solution as a container for such closely related components that may even depend on one another in complex ways, or otherwise share some code, assets or documentation, helps keeps things well organized and ensure proper build order. Using different projects for the different parts helps isolate logical components of the bigger picture (the solution) from one another.

---

To answer your questions:

> I assume something like a client-server system would reside in one
> solution.

I would say "yes" but don't take my word for it.

> Are projects always executables, or is a project built for an assembly?

No. Apart from executables and libraries, I have given you an example where a project produces a Visual Studio wizard. Further, different projects in a solution might use different programming languages.

> I am assuming that multiple executables that have some shared code should go to one place for the code. Where would that be? A separate project?

Yes, the shared code would be a separate project that produces a library. If that library is very general, it might be put in its own, completely separate solution, and developed/maintained/distributed in isolation from the applications using it.

If the executables are closely related and already share the same solution, and also the shared code is very specific to the problem solved by that solution, the library project might just as well be included in that same solution instead of having its own.

> When initializing, projects seem to be more independent entities than they should probably should be. So I think a lot of people end up with relatively random programs lumped into one solution.

Yes, nothings stops you from lumping completely independent projects in one solution. But do you gain anything by doing so? It's really a matter of how well (or badly) your organize your work logically.

> When branching with git, is it typical to have multiple independent
> branching schemes within a single solution (focused on particular
> projects)?

I am not experienced enough to know if it is typical but it certainly sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, a solution should be seen as "evrything that composes your final application".
And in a solution, a project can be any part of this application, e.g. executables, assemblies, etc.

If multiple executables share the same code, all you need is to reference the assembly containing the code in every project that needs it.

For more information abour how Microsoft sees it, check this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b142f8e7.aspx